# C++ boost::asio Variadic template operator in accept handler for boost::asio::basic_socket_acceptor::async_accept()

Tags: c++, boost, network-programming, handler, variadic-templates

I'm trying to create an asynchronous tcp server which accepts connection. I'm about to use an accept handler function object which looks like the following:

```
template <typename Function>
struct callback
{
   Function func_;

   callback()
   {
   }

   callback(Function&& f)
        : func_(std::forward<Function>(f))
   {
   }

   template <typename ...Args>
   void operator() (Args&& ...args)
   {
         func_(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
   }
};
```

My server class:

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

#include <session.hpp>
#include <handler.hpp>
class server
{
private:
    typedef callback<boost::function<void(const boost::system::error_code&, session_ptr&)>> accept_handler;

    boost::asio::io_service& io_service_;
    tcp::acceptor acceptor_;
    accept_handler handler_;

public:
    server(boost::asio::io_service& io_service, short port)
        : io_service_(io_service),
          acceptor_(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), port))
    {
        session_ptr new_session = session_ptr(new session(io_service_));
        auto callback =  boost::bind(&server::handle_accept,
                                     this,
                                     boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                                     new_session);

        handler_ = accept_handler(std::move(callback));


        acceptor_.async_accept(new_session->socket(),
                               handler_);
    }

    void handle_accept(const boost::system::error_code& error, session_ptr new_session)
    {
        if (!error)
        {
            new_session->start();
            new_session.reset(new session(io_service_));

            acceptor_.async_accept(new_session->socket(),
                                   handler_);

        }
    }
};
```

But when I try to compile I get following error:

error: no match for call to ‘(boost::function&)>) (const boost::system::error_code&)’
          func_(std::forward(args)...);

So I must only use handler which meet AcceptHandler requirements

```
struct accept_handler
{
  ...
  void operator()(
      const boost::system::error_code& ec)
  {
    ...
  }
  ...
};
```

or there is a solution to use overloaded variadic template opreator() ?

Comment: Why don't you use a lambda?

Comment: @MichaëlRoy that doesn't make a difference here.

Comment: I see.  What you want is call using std::invoke, or boost::invoke.

Comment: Yeah, I know how to solve problem with boost::bind to cteate boost::function object, it works, but I would like to know if it is possible to use variadic template function object. @MichaëlRoy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ***UPDATED** After realizing the real mistake*:

The good news is: the error is quite simply fixed by changing one line:

```
typedef callback<boost::function<void(const boost::system::error_code&, session_ptr&)>> accept_handler;
```

into

```
typedef callback<boost::function<void(const boost::system::error_code&)>> accept_handler;
```

The previous definition was simply wrong for all reasons:

- it doesn't fit the handler requirements
- it also doesn't match the `bind` expression: `bind(&server::handle_accept, this, asio::placeholders::error, new_session)`. Note it has only 1 placeholder (`asio::placeholders::error`) so it couldn't possibly work with 2 parameters

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f65099a71143710d)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

namespace ba = boost::asio;
using ba::ip::tcp;

struct session : std::enable_shared_from_this<session> {
    session(ba::io_service& svc) : _socket(svc) {}

    void start() {} // do something asynchronously
    tcp::socket& socket() { return _socket; }

    tcp::socket _socket;
};

using session_ptr = std::shared_ptr<session>;

template <typename Function>
struct callback
{
   Function func_;

   callback(Function&& f = {}) : func_(std::forward<Function>(f)) {
   }

   template <typename ...Args>
   void operator() (Args&& ...args) {
       func_(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
   }
};

class server
{
private:
    typedef callback<boost::function<void(const boost::system::error_code&)>> accept_handler;

    ba::io_service& io_service_;
    tcp::acceptor acceptor_;
    accept_handler handler_;

public:
    server(ba::io_service& io_service, short port)
        : io_service_(io_service),
          acceptor_(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), port))
    {
        session_ptr new_session = session_ptr(new session(io_service_));
        handler_ = accept_handler(bind(&server::handle_accept, this, ba::placeholders::error, new_session));

        acceptor_.async_accept(new_session->socket(), handler_);
    }

    void handle_accept(const boost::system::error_code& error, session_ptr new_session)
    {
        if (!error)
        {
            new_session->start();
            new_session.reset(new session(io_service_));

            acceptor_.async_accept(new_session->socket(),
                                   handler_);

        }
    }
};

int main() {
}
```

### Simplify: Remove Redundant Wrappers

The only thing I'd note here is that quite clearly, none `callback<>`, `accept_handler` have any use:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/32ebab1654a526e1)</kbd>**

```
class server
{
private:
    ba::io_service& io_service_;
    tcp::acceptor acceptor_;

public:
    server(ba::io_service& io_service, short port)
        : io_service_(io_service),
          acceptor_(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), port))
    { 
        do_accept();
    }

    void do_accept() {
        session_ptr new_session = session_ptr(new session(io_service_));
        acceptor_.async_accept(new_session->socket(), bind(&server::handle_accept, this, ba::placeholders::error, new_session));
    }

    void handle_accept(const boost::system::error_code& error, session_ptr new_session)
    {
        if (!error) {
            new_session->start();
            do_accept();
        }
    }
};
```

### Even Simpler: Capturing Lambda

You can do without the bind, the placeholder, the `handle_accept` member all at the same time:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/43c2171ae944fa68)</kbd>**

```
class server
{
private:
    ba::io_service& io_service_;
    tcp::acceptor acceptor_;

public:
    server(ba::io_service& io_service, short port)
        : io_service_(io_service),
          acceptor_(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), port))
    { 
        do_accept();
    }

    void do_accept() {
        session_ptr new_session = std::make_shared<session>(io_service_);

        acceptor_.async_accept(new_session->socket(), [this,new_session](const boost::system::error_code& error) {
            if (!error) {
                new_session->start();
                do_accept();
            }
        });
    }
};
```

### Old Answer

In the first reading I had assumed you ran into a classic pitfall I frequently run into with Boost Asio and polymorphic lambdas. Sorry.

Indeed, in the variadic case the concept check cannot verify the handler requirements. My approach here would be to disable the requirement checks:

```
#define BOOST_ASIO_DISABLE_HANDLER_TYPE_REQUIREMENTS 1
```

The main thing lost is friendlier error messages if there is a mismatch:

> Asio 1.6.0 / Boost 1.47
>
> - Added friendlier compiler errors for when a completion handler does not meet the necessary type requirements. When C++0x is available (currently supported for g++ 4.5 or later, and MSVC 10), static_assert is also used to generate an informative error message. This checking may be disabled by defining BOOST_ASIO_DISABLE_HANDLER_TYPE_REQUIREMENTS.

See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/boost_asio/history.html

Comment: Understood, but I still keep gettind the same error. I add define macros at the top of the file "server.hpp", ran qmake(my IDE is Qt creator for addition) and rebuilt the project. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: gcc and boost versions:

gcc (Ubuntu 7.2.0-1ubuntu1~16.04) 7.2.0
boost 1.58.0.1ubuntu1

@sehe

Comment: The problem is that you want to bing to callable::operator<Args...>()(Args...).  You cannot get its address;  you have to call it for some sort of make_() fonction   I really think boost::invoke() (or std::invoke) can help you do what you want. A template is defined and compiled when called, no when it's address is taken.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy, it works for async_write (type of handler callback<boost::function<void(const boost::system::error_code&, size_t)>> ). But in async_accept's handler I need to pass callback<boost::function<void(const boost::system::error_code&, boost::shared_ptr<session>)>>. I disabled handler check type requirements but I still get the same error.

Comment: @zabaz I didn't spot that on first reading. I assumed you ran into the case of non-checkable handler constraints, but that doesn't remove the problem that the handler simply doesn't match the required signature at all: [`void (const boost::system::error_code& ec)`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/AcceptHandler.html). I mentioned this in my answer: _"The main thing lost is friendlier error messages if there is a mismatch"_. You get precisely that: a compiler error because of the signature mismatch.

Comment: Updated the answer with an proper explanation, and a few working answers (with increasing simplicity) /cc @MichaëlRoy

Comment: @sehe, so I only can use boost::bind(&server::handle_accept, this, new_session, boost::asio::placeholders::error) object as handler to avoid this error? Or I can change signature somehow to get it through handler type check requirements?

Comment: Did you see the answer? I show three approaches. You already have the bind in your own code. It's just the callback declaration that was wrong (as I explain in the answer).

Comment: @sehe, sorry I've just seen